# Use grunt to switch HTML elements when switching from development to production environment

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables, gruntjs

I would like to have a dev and a production setup in grunt. I have figured out all of the issues with concatenating, linting and compressing my JS for build and beautifying my libraries during development.

What I would like to do is be able to seemlessly switch my Js source at the app entry point.

I have

```
<!--<script data-main="js/main" src="js/libs/require.js"></script>-->
    <script src="js/main-built.js" ></script>
```

and currenntly I am manually switching the comments when I switch environments. I would like to automate this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [`grunt-targethtml` plugin](https://github.com/changer/grunt-targethtml), which allows you to use different assets for different targets.

```
<!--(if target dev)><!-->
    <script src="dev.js"></script>
<!--<!(endif)-->

<!--(if target dist)>
    <script src="release.js"></script>
<!(endif)-->
```

On the same topic, if you only want to change some configuration options in the Javascript you're using, there is no need to use a different source file: you can use the [`grunt-replace` plugin](http://newtriks.com/2013/11/29/environment-specific-configuration-in-angularjs-using-grunt/).

Comment: Can I use targethtml with watch?

Comment: Yes I can. Just add an html{} child task